# How to return ordered data from database

Tags: php, mysql

Say I've got a mySQL database table with 4 fields:

- link_id (primary key)
- page_id
- anchor_text
- url

My data looks like this:

```
link_id | page_id | anchor_text | url 
1       | 1       | Link One    | http://www.one.com
2       | 1       | Link Two    | http://www.two.com
3       | 2       | Link Three  | http://www.three.com
```

How would I best write a function to get the links for a given page and then use that function to display them?

### **Function:**

```
    function get_page_links($page_id) {

        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "my_db");

        //what's next?

        }
```

**Usage:**

```
$my_links = get_page_links(1);

//do something to parse $my_links
```

**Display:**

```
<a href="http://www.one.com">Link One</a>
<a href="http://www.two.com">Link Two</a>
```

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` somewhere somehow.

Comment: Start with fixing your column names, eg: `page_id` instead of `page-id`.

Comment: I'll edit the post - no need to add complication with poor field names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$q = "SELECT *";
$q.= " FROM yourtablename";
$q.= " WHERE `page-id` = ".(int)$page_id;
$q.= " ORDER BY `link-id`";
```

The backticks might not be necessary, but I'm throwing them in there since you have hyphens in your field names.

Note that there is very basic validation going on here.  By casting `$page_id` to an int before appending it, you ensure it won't be some sort of injection attack.  This isn't a great way to do it, but it will work.

Something like `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is an alternative that should be considered, especially for more general sanitization.

Alternatively:

```
$q = sprintf("SELECT *
              FROM yourtablename
              WHERE `page-id` = %d
              ORDER BY `link-id", $page_id);
```

Which I like better.

---

**Edit** re: now what?

First off, lets not use mysqli, lets use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Second, we don't want to connect to the database on each call of the function, we want to do this once.  So move this out of the function.

```
// Typically this line is in another file and included once, but for now lets just
//  get this out of the function
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', 'root', 'root');

// Your function
function get_page_links($page_id) {
    // Build query
    $q = sprintf("SELECT *
                  FROM yourtablename
                  WHERE `page-id` = %d
                  ORDER BY `link-id`", $page_id);
    // Run Query
    foreach ($db->query($q) as $a) {
        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>'."\n", $a['url'], $a['anchor-text']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats fair -- I assumed it would be cleaned prior to the function.  I'll edit it in.

Comment: Well, that's one [interesting] way to do it... just keep in mind people asking these sorts of questions often don't have much experience.

Comment: Thanks, but rather than getting (rightly) caught up in ensuring $page_id is safe prior to it's use, can you help with the original question? What should the return value of my function look like and how do I use that return value? Looking for best practice here.

Comment: @chris_mac It looks like *any other query* (e.g. `$myslqi->query` see the documentation for a "good example of usage" including error handling)... the original question doesn't leave much to go on. I would likely return a business-object Array (that is, do the "reading" from the mysql inside the singular method). Also *separate* out the connection stuff.

Comment: @pst Sorry for not being clear. So if I return an array, what are the actual contents? I'll want to loop through each of the items in the array to generate my html, but how do I keep the anchor_text and url fields properly associated for each array value?

Comment: Instead of `sprintf()` you could use PDO prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a rather simple query for me

```
SELECT *
    FROM `links_table`
    WHERE `page_id` = $page_id
    ORDER BY `link_id` ASC;
```

This of course is assuming `$page_id` does not come from the user input, and is safely sanitzied. If not, you should be using prepared statements.

Read about **[Executing Statements on MySQLi](http://il.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php)** to learn how to deal with the results this query generates.

---

I'm not proficient at MySQLi, as I prefer PDO. In PDO, I would have done something like so:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param integer $page_id
 * @param PDO     $db
 *
 * @return array
 */
/*
 * First, we give the function the database connection object as an argument.
 * A function to get the page links shouldn't care where you got the connection from!
 */
function get_page_links($page_id, PDO $db) {
    $query = <<<MySQL
SELECT *
    FROM `links_table`
    WHERE `page_id` = :page_id
    ORDER BY `link_id` ASC;
MySQL;
    /*
     * Prepare the query and bind all values to placeholders
     */
    $stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(":page_id", $page_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    /*
     * Fetch all results to an array, and return it
     */
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}

try {
    /*
     * Start new PDO connection for the function
     */
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name", "user", "password");
    //This line tells PDO to throw PDOExceptions in case of errors,
    //which are much easier to handle
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //This lines disables PDO's default emulation for prepared statements. Adds security.
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $links = get_page_links(1, $db);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("There has been an error with the database: " . $e->getMessage());
}

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo "<a href='{$link["url"]}'>{$link["anchor_text"]}</a>";
}
```

Comment: Yep, assume $page_id is safe - just put it in as '1' to simplify.

Comment: So there's the query, but how do I actually use it?

Comment: @chris_mac It's better to *never* (except under very well defined scenarios) assume input is safe - from encoding issues - but to *always* use the proper technique (I would argue placeholders, but `*_escape_string` is an option as with a direct cast to an integer). Consider that even in C#, which is a strongly typed language, I *always* use placeholders.

Comment: @pst Thanks, but rather than getting (rightly) caught up in ensuring $page_id is safe prior to it's use, can you help with the original question? What should the return value of my function look like and how do I use that return value? Looking for best practice here.